# how to work with data offline react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need to develop an app in react native which consumes data from a server, stores the data on the computer and allows me to work with the data offline and then with the internet synchronize with the server, how do you think is the best way to do this?

I have read about realm async and redux persist but I don't know which one can be more recommended or what advice they can give me to handle this type of app

Comment: If you have SQL knowledge then Save data in SQLite when the app in offline mode 
You need to write APIs to send data to the server. If you want to work with NoSql you can use Using Firebase DB when clients go offline, they write new data in their local cache

Comment: Thanks men. how is the data synchronized?

Comment: In firebase When your users go offline, the Realtime Database SDKs use local cache on the device to serve and store changes. When the device comes online, the local data is automatically synchronized. OR if you using SQLite you can check this https://brucelefebvre.com/blog/2018/12/05/sync-react-native-sqlite-db-with-dropbox/